# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the HTML

```
<input id="fileupload" class="button-default" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/php/upload.php" multiple>
```

I'm using jQuery blueimp file upload widget to upload files to the server:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: "json",
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.submit();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

What is wrong with this code? I get no error in the console, checked the upload handler...

Comment: What is exactly not working? File is not uploaded to the server? or on client side side it shows file is uploaded but nothing is upload on the server or else?

Comment: check any error in console

Comment: File isn't uploaded to the server

Comment: if working on server  give upload folder write permissions(0777)

Answer (score 1):

Give Permission 777 to upload folder. Your files will be successfully updated